Align vertices from top of the cylinder to a cube surface at angle without using a boolean or similar?
Is it possible to align vertices by z axes from the top of the cylinder to a cube surface at an angle without using a boolean or similar operation?


The same question is is it possible to align cylinder vertices to the surface of another cylinder or UV sphere?


Investigate using the Shrinkwrap Modifier. The first part of this tutorial shows how to use it.

Thanks, John this is it!

@user200173 could you kindly mark the checkmark on the left of the answer post that helped you fix your problem?

Select the vertices that have to be projected, press Ctrl G (Assign to a new Vertex group); I renamed the vertex group as "align".
Add a Shrinkwrap modifier, limit its action to the "align" vertex group, set its Wrap method as "Project", choose Z axis, tick both Positive and negative if needed, and select the object to project onto as Target (Cube or sphere or anything).
Apply the Shrinkwrap modifier to make the change permanent.

